# Was the abbreviation "PC" for "Personal computer" in wide use before the IBM PC?

Tags: etymology, abbreviations, acronyms

I am aware of the history of the term *PC* after the IBM PC, and I'm aware that the term *Personal Computer* has existed long before the IBM PC. However, what I don't know is if the abbreviation "PC" for "personal computer" was in common use before then.

Can anyone give me any evidence that it was or was not in common use, at least among computer enthusiasts, before this time?

I've Googled around but it's a difficult thing to search for. The Wikipedia page seems to imply that it was, but it's not sourced and is slightly ambiguous as to whether it's actually talking about the abbreviation, compared to the term.

Comment: Speaking from personal knowledge/experience, "PC" and "personal computer" were not in wide use prior to the IBM PC.  No doubt someone had used the term somewhere, but the industry was still thrashing about for a term to use (after "minicomputer" and "microcomputer" became poor descriptions).

Comment: A quick check to google ngrams shows that PC has been used quite a bit before IBM PC but as it says, PC could stand for many things and may not relate to personal computer.

Comment: I do see, incidental to Ngram, that Commodore was using the term "personal computer" in 1979.  And the industry rag *Computerworld* was using the term in 1978.

Comment: @HotLicks Right, but the OP is asking whether *PC* was in use for the concept, not *personal computer* or *personal computing*. The *BYTE* reviews I've seen use the term *microcomputer* until 1981, for example. NGrams searches for things like "Apple PC" or "Tandy PC" turn up zilch.

Comment: In the eighties I remember people would use the term *PC* to refer specifically to the IBM model, to distinguish it from what was then called a 'clone'. But *PC* is in regular daily use, and has been for generations to mean *Police Constable* the lowest uniformed rank in any British police force.

Comment: Yes, the term was in widespread use.  Mainly used for products from the likes of Wang and Northstar, which were larger than microcomputers but didn't have multitasking.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Personal_Computer) suggests that 'Personal Computer' was in use from the early 70s at the latest, but that "PC" came into widespread use to mean 'IBM (PC) compatible'. *PC World* magazine was launched in late 1982, more than a year after the IBM product appeared. The (British) magazine *Personal Computer World* began in 1978.

Comment: ... and the first issue of *PC Magazine* was dated 'Feb/March 1982'.  It might be instructional to find an original, contemporary review of the first  IBM Personal Computer. I'd say that if such an article *explains* the abbreviation, to a presumably well-informed readership, then you could assume that it wasn't in widespread use.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_personal_computers#Etymology) gives a 1962 usage and points out Byte and creative computing  magazines using similar terms in 1975  and points to [Datamation](http://www.atariarchives.org/bcc2/showpage.php?page=11)

Comment: @choster - All I can say is that I don't recall "PC" being used before the IBM PC.  In order for it to be used it must be recognized, and there was no event that would tend to make people recognize it as an acronym for "personal computer" until IBM came out with their "PC".

Comment: Personal Computer World was abbreviated to PCW by April 1981 https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iUz6LTd7vdIC&pg=PA298&dq=%22personal+computer+world%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CFEQ6AEwCTgKahUKEwiNwOn9g7PIAhWLuhQKHQcdCgE#v=onepage&q=%22personal%20computer%20world%22&f=false so I think PC was in use by then

Comment: Although PCW Nov 81 does not use PC to refer to the IBM Personal Computer http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/1706/Personal-Computer-World-November-1981/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In **September 1977**  (September 19-21, 1977 to be precise) the International Conference on Cybernetics and Society included discussion of the *Personal Computer (PC)".  The proceedings of this meeting are not available openly on the internet, but the "Snippet View" from Google Books shows it clearly [here](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Q3M-AQAAIAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=%22Personal%20computer%20%28PC%29%22):

> ...personal computer (PC) can then be easily tailored to individual
>   user's needs in his office, at his place of business, or at his home.
>   Our ultimate objective is to make the PC into its user's "intelligent
>   assistant" for real-life situations.

This clearly predates the 1981 release of the IBM PC, although it's not concrete evidence of "widespread" use, as requested by the OP.  This document can be found in many University libraries around the world, and if someone has access to a copy, I'd love to know who was promoting the PC in 1977 :-)

Comment: That document seems incredibly hard to find. The closest to me is in France, as far as I could tell from a look online. I could check physically in a few days in my university's library but I'm not expecting to find it, since I couldn't see it in the web catalogue. But thanks a lot for linking that!

Comment: The fact that the author felt the need to explicitly introduce the abbreviation in this text could be taken as evidence of its **not** being in common use at the time.